# avoiding setting a cookie based on a specific URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cookies

I am setting up a cookie based on the user first visit on a website. So every time a new user visit the website I am redirecting them to the landing page otherwise the user will see the index page directly (since time time the cookie is already in the user's browser).

Now what I am trying to achieve is that I would like skip the landing page redirect based on a specific URL (for both new users and existing users).

This is how I am checking the new visit and setting up a redirect cookie.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    landingPageOnFirstVisit();
    createCookie('landingRedirect', 'true', '60');
});

function landingPageOnFirstVisit() {
    var setCookieForLanding = readCookie('landingRedirect');
    if (!setCookieForLanding) {
        window.location = "/en/landing";
    }
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

How do I make sure that if user visit the website directly using the below mentioned URL pattern: the redirection process would not occur and we wont set any cookies.

https://www.domain.com/en/page?usePromo=XXXXXX 

(where XXXXXX are numbers and changes everytime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
    if (location.href.indexOf("usePromo")==-1) {
      landingPageOnFirstVisit();
      createCookie('landingRedirect', 'true', '60');
    }
});
```